# Improve multiple SQL query performance in python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a Postgre database that I update everyday to hold stock tickers and prices. I use this database to download stock prices for various dates in a script I'm working on. However, I've noticed that the SQL statement queries taking significantly longer to perform when executed in Python vs. the psql command line.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to improve the performance of the code below? I've tried combining the SQL queries into one long query but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you!

```
    for ticker in sectorStocks:

    # Pull closing price for startDate
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT close_price FROM dailyprices WHERE ticker=%s AND price_date=%s", (ticker,startDate))
        tickerStartRaw = cur.fetchone()

    # Check to ensure there is market data for the date used
    while not tickerStartRaw:
        startDate = startDate - BDay(1)
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT close_price FROM dailyprices WHERE ticker=%s AND price_date=%s", (ticker,startDate))
            tickerStartRaw = cur.fetchone()

    tickerStartPrice = tickerStartRaw[0]

    # Pull closing price for endDate
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT close_price FROM dailyprices WHERE ticker=%s AND price_date=%s", (ticker,endDate))
        tickerEndRaw = cur.fetchone()

    # Check to ensure there is market data for the date used
    while not tickerEndRaw:
        endDate = endDate - BDay(1)
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT close_price FROM dailyprices WHERE ticker=%s AND price_date=%s", (ticker,endDate))
            tickerEndRaw = cur.fetchone()

    tickerEndPrice = tickerEndRaw[0]
```

Comment: You code looks solid.  Have you tried using the `timeit` module to diagnose which piece of the code is causing the hold up?  EDIT: I just noticed the `for` loop at the top of your code block.  How big is `sectorStocks`?  It could be that the overhead of opening and closing all those connection is slowing you down.

Comment: Make sure there's an index on both the `ticker` and `price_date` columns.

Comment: Basically you have to get rid of the three loops in your code. For more detailed help you have to give the table structure, some example data, and the desired output.

Comment: It's parsing through a list of around 400 tickers. I used timeit and it takes over 600 seconds to go through the entire code block.

Comment: Klaus - I have the loops because there is a chance that there may not be historical data for the ticker (ie: an IPO without historical data) for the date given. By going back one business day it generally fixes the error. I'm not sure what else to do to stop the script from crashing in the event of no price history.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with python, but use bind variables (don't believe that's why this python syntax is doing).

Using bind variable make it seem like the same statement repeated, meaning the database doesn't have to reparse the query for each call, but still get the requested data because you've assigned the actual bind variables before executing the query.

In this case, each SQL statement is going to be seen as new and requires parsing each and every time.  For large query volume it can make a large difference.

Comment: I'll look into binding the startDate and endDate. Given I"m parsing 400+ tickers, this may help

Comment: definitely, and will scale better as you add more tickers

Answer (score 0):

After digging into this more I realized the only real problem was the delay with thousands of queries to the database.

I was able to improve the script time significantly by combing all the SQL pulls into one statement. I'm also looking into doing one initial data dump from the database for all the "tickers" used, so that the whole script only uses one SQL pull.

```
    for ticker in sectorStocks:
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT price_date, close_price FROM dailyprices WHERE ticker=%s AND (price_date=%s or price_date=%s)", (ticker, startDate, endDate))
            tickerPricesRaw = cur.fetchall()

        if(len(tickerPricesRaw) < 2):
            print("Error pulling price data for %s - going to next ticker" % ticker)
            continue
        else:
            ......
```